# Kinematics: 2 dimensional vs. 3 dimensional motion

Tags: kinematics, terminology, projectile

I just studied kinematics and saw "throwing a ball in air" as an example of a 2 dimensional motion. I have a doubt that if we are throwing a ball in space, it should also have a $z$ coordinate, so why is it 2D motion and not 3D motion?

Comment: Naming of the coordinates is arbitrary. I can say $y$ is horizontal and $x$ is vertical. How can it move in $z$ after I throw it, unless the wind blows?

Comment: @BillN thanks i got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually considered to be 2-D. Unless some wind or external perpendicular horizontal force acts, the motion of the ball can be described on a plane with just two variables. So, in most cases, as horizontal winds are not considered, throwing a ball is considered as 2-D.

Another way to think about it is by drawing a line to every instantaneous point during fright from the initial point. All of those lines will lie in a plane, so it can be considered as 2-D motion.

Comment: i saw " bird flying in air " as an example for 3d motion so what's the difference between a bird in space and a ball in space?

Comment: The bird can, by its own will, move right/left and up/down, while moving forward. Balls, being non-living, usually tend to follow 2-D motion (up/Down). It can move to right or left (like Magnus effect, which you will study later), but in kinematics, we ignore such situations.

Comment: Thanks a lot my doubt is cleared 